# Error using default value for templates

Tags: c++, templates, smart-pointers

```
template <class T, class FPTR = void (void *)> 
class CSmartPtr
{
public :
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
//  Constructors and Destructor
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
CSmartPtr()
{
    m_TData = NULL;
    m_deleter = NULL;
}

CSmartPtr(T* TData)
{
    m_TData = TData;
    m_deleter = NULL;
}

CSmartPtr(T* TData, FPTR *deleter)
{
    m_TData = TData;
    m_deleter = deleter;
}

~CSmartPtr()
{
    if (NULL == m_deleter)
    {
        delete m_TData;
    }
    else
    {
        m_deleter(m_TData);
    }
}

T *const operator-> () const
{
    return m_TData;
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
// Getter methods
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
T *const get() const
{
    return m_TData;
}

void reset(T* TData)
{
    if (NULL != m_TData)
    {
        if (NULL == m_deleter)
        {
            delete m_TData;
        }
        else
        {
            m_deleter(m_TData);
        }
    }

    m_TData = TData;
}

private :

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
//  Private data members
//
//  fUnicodeForm
//      This is the Unicode XMLCh format of the string.
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
T *m_TData;
FPTR *m_deleter;
};

int main( void )
{
CSmartPtr<BYTE> apbySrcBuff;      // This doesnt work.
    CSmartPtr<BYTE, (void) (void *)> apbySrcBuff;      // This works.
getchar();
return TRUE;
}
```

I am absolutely new to `templates`, and i am stuck with the above problem, from hours.
Tried to solve it on my own, but did not succeed.

The error is `Error 1   error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments`
 
The line is
`m_deleter(m_TData);`

Comment: What is the error you're getting? Your code compiles, if I declare typedef BYTE and const bool TRUE. Also your work and doesn't work lines are identical.

Comment: You work and doesn't work lines are the same. What is the error message?

Comment: So sorry, i have posted the edited question..

Answer (score 0):

You need the following at the top of your code:

```
#include <cstdio>

typedef char BYTE;
bool TRUE = true;
```

and after commenting out one of your identical:

CSmartPtr apbySrcBuff;

lines, it all compiles.

Comment: The code does compile, i am using VC++ compiler. I am coding on windows so the above statements are not required.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested it [at ideone](http://ideone.com/FdGJ7S) and works perfectly (It terminates with a runtime error, but thats your smart_ptr implementation, wich I didn't debugged).

The only issue I have finded is that the second declaration uses extra parens, `(void)(void*)` and the compilation fails here (***I have had no problem with the first declaration***).

Comment: I have sent those extra parens, so that i could use them, it is should be a pointer to a function. however i am not able to do so.